# Can we join table based on their length using len()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have 2 table

Table A

```
nameA   
---------       
1234A   
1235A
```

Table B

```
nameB   
----------  
1234        
1235
```

I want to join 1235A with 1235 and my expected outpout is

```
nameA   nameB          
1234A   1234        
1235A   1235
```

Can we join both the table using len() of the name column

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What if A had more rows than B?  What if two rows in B had 1235?  The exactly logic you want is not clear.

Comment: lets just say there is only 2 rows in both the table in tableA we have 1234A and in tableB we have 1234. can we use substring on tableA and then join with tableb something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this - it matches names on either side up to the length of the smaller name. If the length parameter of `substring` is greater than the length of the input string it returns the original string.

```
select * from
TableA A inner join TableB B
on SUBSTRING( A.NameA, 1, len(B.NameB) ) = SUBSTRING( B.NameB, 1, len(A.NameA) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from
TableA a join TableB b on
Left (a.nameA,4)= b.nameB
```

Try the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select a.name, b.name
from a join
     b
     on a.name like b.name + '%';
```

This question is very different from your original question.  If you have another question, don't modify this one.  Ask it as a new question.